# Can I Use Count Case to Display result of Conditional Count in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have database table called **data** in my database table structure like this :

```
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+
| id |    date    | name | absent | late_in |
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+
|  1 | 2016-09-09 | John | Hadir  |      20 |
|  2 | 2016-09-09 | Sean | Hadir  |         |
|  3 | 2016-09-09 | Alea | Libur  |         |
|  4 | 2016-09-09 | Rina | Hadir  |         |
|  5 | 2016-09-08 | John | Hadir  |         |
|  6 | 2016-09-08 | Sean | Ijin   |         |
|  7 | 2016-09-08 | Alea | Hadir  |         |
|  8 | 2016-09-08 | Rina | Hadir  |      10 |
|  9 | 2016-09-07 | John | Sakit  |         |
| 10 | 2016-09-07 | Sean | Hadir  |         |
| 11 | 2016-09-07 | Alea | Hadir  |         |
| 12 | 2016-09-07 | Rina | Hadir  |         |
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+
```

and I want to display in Html to this :

```
+------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+---------+
| Name | Hadir | Sakit | Ijin | Alpa | Libur | late_in |
+------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+---------+
| John |     2 |     1 |    - |    - |     - | 20 Min  |
| Sean |     2 |     - |    1 |    - |     - |      -  |
| Alea |     2 |     - |    - |    - |     1 |      -  |
| Rina |     3 |     - |    - |    - |     - | 10 Min  |
+------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+---------+
```

I've try using this query,

```
SELECT date, name, absent,
SUM(late_in) as late,
COUNT(CASE WHEN absent = 'Hadir' THEN absent ELSE 0 END) AS hadir, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN absent = 'Sakit' THEN absent ELSE 0 END) AS sakit, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN absent = 'Izin/Cuti' THEN absent ELSE 0 END) AS izin,
COUNT(CASE WHEN absent = 'Alpha' THEN absent ELSE 0 END) AS alpha,
FROM data GROUP BY name WHERE date between '$foo' and '$foo2'
```

but I don't know why, there's no data to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT 
    name as 'Name ',
    SUM(CASE WHEN absent='Hadir' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as 'Hadir',
    SUM(CASE WHEN absent='Sakit' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as 'Sakit',
    SUM(CASE WHEN absent='Ijin' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as 'Ijin',
    SUM(CASE WHEN absent='Alpa' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as 'Alpa',
    SUM(CASE WHEN absent='Libur' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as 'Libur',
    SUM(late_in) as 'late_in'
FROM
     data
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY id ASC

Comment: Please code format your response and add brief explanation what you did to resolve OP's situation.

Comment: @Parfait sorry about the formatting , I am new to posting . Please try the above solution . The reason you are getting no data back might also be because you have a syntax error in the code "Should not have a comma at this line" COUNT(CASE WHEN absent = 'Alpha' THEN absent ELSE 0 END) AS alpha,  .

Comment: I've Try ur code, and works fine by replacing SUM(CASE to COUNT(CASE ... Thanks so much Likho :)